# Deforming a meshed part after another

Tags: mesh, surface-deform

I want to be as clear as possible. The red part is the reference here, and I want to deform the gray part in that way that it will look the same as the red one. The ideea is that the red one is deformed because of the injection process and to simulate the structural behaviour I need to transform the gray part.
If you can give me some directions to some specific tutorials, or similar, because I am also new in Blender community. Thank tou very much indeed.[[image: the overall picture of the partsalso a better view of situation]

Comment: Hello, do you mean that the grey one will be animated or not?

Comment: hello, i don't want to animate nothing, just to deform physically

Comment: If the grey one needs to look like the red one, why not duplicate the red one and make it look like what you want with some extrudings etc?

Comment: Ok let me be more specific, the part itself(gray) is made by injection process, and after the cooling of the part(red) there are some deformations, contractions of the material and so on. I don't and can't measure the deformations from the red part after it's cooled, so this is why I need. Deform, re-mesh and export the mesh and introduce it to some FEA software

Comment: Okay, but injection process, cooling, measuring etc. sounds like real world objects. We are talking here about a virtual 3D model. Deforming inside Blender to the shape of another object only works with another 3D object, not a real object. So when you have the red object in Blender's 3D space and you want the grey to be the same, just duplicate it. If you don't have the red object in 3D space and cannot measure it, how is Blender supposed to deform an object to match the shape?